# Strange folder creation in windows

Tags: windows, winapi, active-directory, directory

I need some help in understanding a problem. Here is the scenario. We have a windows domain controller machine and several machines in that domain. (Everything in windows 2008). In one of the machines in that domain (machine name  AlphaSiter) our own custom java based product is installed. To log on into our product, you have to provide a user/password combo which is validated against the active directory. Now here is the scenario.

1. Log into the domain controller and create a user (say David) in the active directory and set the “User must change password in next login option”.
2. Go to the machine called  AlphaSiter where our custom product is installed and try to login to our product with the newly created user credentials and then change password successfully.

The side affect is that in the AlphaSiter machine in C:\Users the user folder is created..that is c:\Users\David. Also this folder is only created if at the time of user creation the “User must change password in next login option” is set. This user folder is not created if the option is unchecked. We are not creating the folder programmatically from our code. So I am wondering how  this folder is getting created.Is it something that windows does internally?
Any help on this would be appreciated as I have to give explanation to our customer ---:)

Comment: What is presenting the password change prompt? It sounds like it's doing a full login to present UI to the user.

Comment: Folks considering voting to close may want to read again, this *is* a programming question. :-)

Comment: What API are you using to check the password?  My guess is that this is probably something to do with Windows encryption; when a password is changed a user's private key (which lives in their profile, i.e., c:\Users\<username>) has to be re-encrypted, so perhaps the profile is being created as a side-effect of the system attempting to do this.  Have you checked whether there's a NTUSER.DAT being created in the folder?  These files are hidden.

Comment: We are seeing a similar issue with a asp.net web app that is setting a user password in AD - that user folders are being created on the server. Not only is NTUSER.DAT being created but some .regtrans-ms and blf files as well.

Answer (score 0):

The user's profile folder is always created when there is some profile information that needs to be stored. It may be some registry settings in HKCU hive.
You can use RegMon to track regitry activity.